# react: router : creating reusable component for routes so that can be used as subroutes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to resuse component which has some routes that needs to repeated for multiple routes.

```
export const DocumentsRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path={abc} element={<component1 />} />
      <Route path={bcd} element={<component2 />} />
      <Route path={def} element={<component3 />} />
      <Route path={af} element={<component4 />} />
      <Route path={ef} element={<component5 />} />
      <Route path="ef" element={<component6 />} />
    </>
  );
};

<Route path="packages/:packageId" element={<DocumentsPackageRoot />}>
     <DocumentsRoutes />
</Route>
```

But i am facing the below error

```
history.ts:480 Uncaught Error: [DocumentsRoutes] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
at invariant (history.ts:480:11)
at components.tsx:582:5
at react.development.js:1195:17
at react.development.js:1158:17
at mapIntoArray (react.development.js:1049:23)
at mapChildren (react.development.js:1157:3)
at Object.forEachChildren [as forEach] (react.development.js:1194:3)
at createRoutesFromChildren (components.tsx:566:18)
at components.tsx:577:9
at react.development.js:1195:17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route` component can really only render other `Route` components. `DocumentsRoutes` is not a `Route` component.

### As Nested Routes

If `DocumentsPackageRoot` renders an `Outlet` component then you can render `DocumentsRoutes` on a "catch-all" nested route.

```
export const DocumentsRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path={abc} element={<component1 />} />
      <Route path={bcd} element={<component2 />} />
      <Route path={def} element={<component3 />} />
      <Route path={af} element={<component4 />} />
      <Route path={ef} element={<component5 />} />
      <Route path="ef" element={<component6 />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

```
<Route path="packages/:packageId" element={<DocumentsPackageRoot />}>
  <Route path="*" element={<DocumentsRoutes />} />
</Route>
```

Or you can render the routes directly as ***nested*** routes of the `"packages/:packageId"` path,

```
<Route path="packages/:packageId" element={<DocumentsPackageRoot />}>
  <Route path={abc} element={<component1 />} />
  <Route path={bcd} element={<component2 />} />
  <Route path={def} element={<component3 />} />
  <Route path={af} element={<component4 />} />
  <Route path={ef} element={<component5 />} />
  <Route path="ef" element={<component6 />} />
</Route>
```

### As Descendent Routes

Or wrap them in another `Routes` component and render them as ***descendent*** routes in `DocumentsPackageRoot`. The parent route will need to append the wildcard `"*"` matcher to its path, i.e. `path="packages/:packageId/*"`, so descendent routes can also be matched and rendered.

```
export const DocumentsRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path={abc} element={<component1 />} />
      <Route path={bcd} element={<component2 />} />
      <Route path={def} element={<component3 />} />
      <Route path={af} element={<component4 />} />
      <Route path={ef} element={<component5 />} />
      <Route path="ef" element={<component6 />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

```
const DocumentsPackageRoot = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <DocumentsRoutes /> // <-- descendent routes rendered here
    ...
  );
};
```

```
<Route path="packages/:packageId/*" element={<DocumentsPackageRoot />} />
```

Comment: thank you for the inputs.if I have only * it is working properly, 
           <Route path="packages/:packageId" element={<DocumentsPackageRoot />}>
              <Route path="*" element={< DocumentsRoutes />} />
            </Route>

Comment: @Raphael Yes, that's a bit of an odd way to "code split" the routes but it's perfectly valid and I hadn't considered it. I'll update my answer. Thanks, and cheers and good luck!